# In Angular have a component which get a component as input parameter

Tags: angular, input, components

I have a horizontal-slider component which need another component as input. I searched a lot and found this solution:

In slider ts:

```
export class HorizontalSliderComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {

  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any> | undefined;}
```

In slider html:

```
  <div class="placehoder">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" (scroll)="onScroll()" (mousedown)="onMouseDown()" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"></ng-container>
  </div>
```

and than I should use it in a third component like appcomponent:

```
 <app-horizontal-slider [template]="TopicRowComponent">
  </app-horizontal-slider>
```

The TopicRowComponent is my component which I want to pass as input:

```
export class TopicRowComponent {

  public topics: Topic[] = [];
}
```

But there when I want to use it I get an compile error:

> Type TopicRowComponent is not assignable to type TemplateRef | undefined

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance